# Managing Permissions inside Highlighted Content Web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-pages, highlighted-content-web-part

Let's say I created a page and inside I added a Highlighted Content Web part.

How can I manage the rights and permissions of the users?

I don't want every user to be able to modify the the highlighted content web part or change that page in specific.

Any more information or advice is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Site members will have edit access and will be able to modify pages, while site visitors will have read-only access. So simply ensure your users who shouldn't modify pages are in the site visitors group.

If users also need to modify content elsewhere on the site, then this gets trickier. One option is to split that content to a different site. Another option is to reassess whether or not its critical to block users from editing pages, considering that we have version history to fall back on if a user messes something up.

But if it is critical to lock down specific pages, then pages do exist in the "site pages" library, and it is possible to set permissions on an individual file in this library (or any library). Though, doing so is challenging, as its always easier in SharePoint to share files out to a wider audience than to restrict a file to a narrower audience. You'll need to break permissions inheritance and change the permissions of the members group from edit to read. (you'll need to be an owner to do this). These actions can be done from the advanced permissions screen of the individual file. But again, please avoid this option if possible. Usually, people don't refer to these types of permission changes positively after a few months have passed.

Answer (score 1):

Best Possible solution for your requirement is to give the **Read (View) Only** permissions to the users who should not edit the page or modify the the highlighted content web part.

If you want user to not modify only the specific page then you need to break the inheritance on that particular page and then grant the permissions on that page.
For this follow below steps:

1. Go to the Site Pages/Pages library where you have created page.
2. Click on the ellipsis(...) next to your page.
3. Select **Manage**.
4. Scroll down on the new popup opened and select **Advanced** on the right bottom side.
5. Select **Stop Inheriting Permissions**.
6. Then change the permissions of individual groups/users and set it to the **Read**.
7. You can keep the **Edit** permission for the users who can edit the page.

[Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).